# I want to create a drop-down subcategory under a category in my navbar

Tags: html

I almost created it
but there is still an important part to creating another subcategory inside the subcategory.

[image]

In this picture category is 'Platform' and subcategory is 'PC' and I want to create another subcategory called 'game' inside the 'PC'.
The problem is that when I click on the PC, the drop-down does not work

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">    
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">

                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#mobile_menu" data-toggle="collapse"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="mobile_menu">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <!-- from her -->
                            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Platforms<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">PC<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href="#">game</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <!-- to here -->
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Any suggest to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap natively doesn't support multilevel dropdowns natively. You can try to add some `css` and `jquery` to the code to achieve them. Here is a good explanation in [w3schools](https://w3schools.com) which you can refer to:

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h

Comment: Luckily I found a multilevel dropdowns natively made with Bootstrap, jquery and CSS just a few hours ago. Anyway, thank you.